# Bash script : problem with my substraction

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I would like to make a script that will calculate the difference of download time between two curl.

For example with this command :

```
curl -s -w 'total : %{time_total}\n' https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04.1/ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso -o ubuntu.iso >> total.txt
```

My curl command will be run each day and I would like to make a substraction between the value of the day and the value of the previous day. For that, I will save the `time_total` value of each day in an external file called total.txt :

```
total : 77,844315
total : 95,531319
total : 91,270609
total : 79,185359
total : 94,861921
```

For that, this is my script :

```
#!/bin/bash

Previous_value=$(cat total.txt| awk '{print $3}' | tail -n 2 | head -n 1 )
Current_value=$(cat total.txt | awk '{print $3}' | tail -n 2 | tail -n 1 )

echo "Yesterday download time : "$Previous_value"s"
echo "Today download time : "$Current_value"s"

test=$(($Current_value-$Previous_value))

echo "Download : + "$test"s"
```

Output :

```
Yesterday download time : 79,185359s
Today download time : 94,861921s
Download : + 185359s
```

The result should be `Download : + 15.676562s` but currently the result is `Download : + 185359s`. Someone to tell me why ?

Comment: Can it be because of the comma instead of the dot? Also, bash only uses integers to calculate.

Comment: Hello, I don't think so. Here the output  if I change the comma for the dot `Yesterday download time : 79.185359s
Today download time : 94.861921s
./script.sh: line 9: 94.861921-79.185359: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".861921-79.185359")
Download : + s`

Comment: bash cannot do floating point arithmetic, only integers allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more precise math use `bc`. Also make sure you are entering valid numbers. `bc` only interprets decimals for separating whole and fractional components so you may want to translate those commas to decimals: `tr ',' '.'`

Instead of:

```
echo $(( $A - $B ))
```

Do:

```
bc -l <<< "$A - $B"
```

---

Specifically for your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

Previous_value=$(cat total.txt| awk '{print $3}' | tail -n 2 | head -n 1 | tr ',' '.')
Current_value=$(cat total.txt | awk '{print $3}' | tail -n 2 | tail -n 1 | tr ',' '.')

echo "Yesterday download time : "${Previous_value}"s"
echo "Today download time : "${Current_value}"s"

test=$( bc -l <<< "${Current_value} - ${Previous_value}" )

echo "Download : + "$test"s"
```

Comment: That "pipe to[sic] a deleter might help" you drown.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment? Could you please explain and help me learn. I'm a bit new to this. What did you mean by "drown"?

Comment: The problem @Roadowl mentions is that whenever you remove a comma from 1234,5678, you don't know the exact value. You could say that milliseconds are not useful for download time and only use integers instead. Then it becomes fairly easy: `a=1234,5678; echo ${a/,*/}`.

Comment: Aha this is that other way of using a comma! To denote fractional components: 1(1/2) = 1,5. I misunderstood the post to be using the comma to denote triplet orders of magnitude: 100000 -> 100,000 (One hundred thousand). Perhaps translating commas to periods would be more appropriate: `tr ',' '.'`